# Swift Firebase set criteria for query

Tags: swift, firebase

Are there a way to create rules for firebase query for example

get all child who's lastname = xxxxx but firstname does not equal = aaaa

Comment: You can only have a condition on a single property in a Firebase Database query. This has been discussed a few times before, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. For some use-cases it's possible to combine the values into a single property. If that's the case for you, you might want to have a look at this [library that automates part of the process](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase).

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion